# install: illegal option -- D

Tags: macos, terminal, development

In linux the command install has these options (among others): (from the man page)

```
-d, --directory
          treat all arguments as directory names; create all components of the specified directories

-D     create all leading components of DEST except the last, then copy SOURCE to DEST
```

On the mac manage there is this option:

```
-d      Create directories.  Missing parent directories are created as required.
```

I am attempting to install a library using a makefile and am getting this error on the mac:

```
install: illegal option -- D
```

This is caused by the command install being used to copy a .h file.  Would the `-d` option work the same?  Or is there a way to do this that would work on both platforms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lowercase "d" should work. If it doesn't, you can install GNU install with Homebrew coreutils which will provide the "D" flag.

Answer (score 1):

macOS lower-case `-d` is fairly different from Linux upper-case `-D`.

On Linux, you can do

```
install -D path/to/file.ext target/dir/file.ext
```

and it'll create `target/dir` if it doesn't exist yet and then copy `path/to/file.ext` into it.

On macOS, `install -d path/to` requires that `path/to` is a directory, and it'll create that directory and its parent directories. If you pass a path to a file like `install -d my/file.ext`, it'll complain `install: my/file.ext exists but is not a directory`. You can use `install -d` to create several directories in one invocation like `install -d my/first/dir my/second/dir`, and it'll create both directories. This is *very different* from `install -D my/first/dir my/second/dir` in Linux, where it'll copy `my/first/dir` to `my/second/dir`, creating parent directories as needed.

I think the portable (*) alternative to

```
install -D path/to/my/file.ext target/path/file.ext
```

is:

```
mkdir -p $(dirname target/path/file.ext)
install path/to/my/file.ext target/path/file.ext
```

*: On very very old operating systems, `mkdir -p` has bugs. That's why binutils et al use a script called `mkinstalldirs` instead of `mkdir -p`. I think nowadays `mkdir -p` is probably fine, but you can go looking ofr `mkinstalldirs` if you're curious.